# Seemingly corrupted template-info.json break Analytics package

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, crm-analytics, retrieve

I have a Managed Package with an Analytics Template. For no apparent reasons (no changes in the Git waveTemplates folder), I am unable to:

**Upload new package versions:**

> Expected same number of external file entries between
> `template-info.json` and metadata in template MyTemplate

or **SFDX Retrieve**

[image]

> ERROR running `force:source:retrieve`:  UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected
> error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:
> 1754985807-36099 (794611615)

For me actual files and template-info.json look perfectly in shape.

[image]

Comment: I checked internally and could see this same error was fixed as part of bug #W-8117799 last year. I followed up by asking for feedback by quoting this post and will let you know as I hear back. Thank you

Comment: Any updates on this @Swetha? Any chance you can redirect this internally? My Customer is unable to make any progress. Development is halted.

Comment: I've not got any response yet. Considering customer impact, can you log a support case(including the repro steps, access) and share the case number here so I can own,take it forward. Thanks

Comment: @Swetha I created Partner Case #44215072. Please advise with next steps.

Comment: @Swetha would you be so kind and put your thoughts and workarounds here as an answer? In the end, you helped unlock my package and my org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of troubleshooting based bug #W-8117799, my idea was to `decouple` the associated template(FmaPoc) from the App(FmaPoc), then `delete` this template and `recreate` it.

I was able to decouple template(`Click path: AnalyticsStudio> Browse> Templates> click dropdown of FmaPoc> Decouple)` and tried to delete the template(`Click path: AnalyticsStudio> Browse> Templates> click dropdown of FmaPoc>Delete`). This helped in unblocking the retrieval/package upload operations at the moment as the GACK is no longer reproducible.

The concerned product development team has filed internal investigations `#W-12629854` and `#W-12652248` to track future occurrences/debug this GACK.

Currently, in your scenario, since the template is part of managed released package, it cannot be deleted, and it cannot be recreated as well from the app because it would throw

> Error creating template:
> insights.api.template.exceptions.TemplateAlreadyExists: A template
> with the same name [FmaPoc] already exists

The suggestion is to create a different app from the existing template, name it something other, and then create a template from that.